# MS SQL Server Extract Integer from column, increment by 1 and load the number back into column

Tags: sql-server, etl

I have a table with a column (Integer). In a MS Sql Server 2005 stored procedure I want to take the value in that column, increment it by 1 and update the column to be the incremented value. This column is a counter so each row in the table will have a different counter, IE: I can't just put a trigger on the column to auto increment it or something like that. I have some code as listed below, but all it does is update the column to be 1.

```
SELECT ControlNo = @c
    FROM MedicaidInterchange
    WHERE 1=1
    AND Interkey = @InterKey;

    SET @c = @c +1;

    UPDATE MedicaidInterchange
    SET InterDate = @d
    , InterTime = @t
    , ControlNo = @c
    WHERE 1=1
    AND Interkey = @InterKey;
```

Will someone please help me figure out where my code is failing? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: when you dynamically build a query it makes it so that all of the possible lines in your where clause will have an "AND" in front of them. Unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is this line:

```
SELECT ControlNo = @c
```

This is the same as:

```
SELECT @c as ControlNo
```

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
| column_alias = expression
```

You probably meant to write:

```
SELECT @c = ControlNo
```

But not sure if you need a variable here.  You can refer to old values on the right hand side of `SET`:

```
UPDATE  MedicaidInterchange
SET     ControlNo = ControlNo + 1
WHERE   Interkey = @InterKey
```

Comment: Works exactly as asked for. Thanks.